# Is HTML validation and XSS validation required in API side?

Tags: api, security, xss, webapi, websecurity

We are developing few API which going to expose to outside vendors through APIM. So as API provider do we need to take preventive action to avoid DOM injection or Crosstie scripting (Stored XSS Attacks, Reflected XSS Attacks, DOM Based XSS Attacks ).When we did some research all of this issue is triggered while rendering in browsers we didn't find any security threat by saving this as string in to DB ( we properly handle SQl injection). As our API vendors can be Desktop /web / mobile. So any suggestion on this and how to implement will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must validate any income data that ingress in your API.

Even if the injected code does not threaten your API, if a client uses an "eval" in the data received from the API it can be a threat.

Typically the framework that you are using to create the API provides mechanisms to validate, for example, if you API is PHP + Laravel this is the way https://www.cloudways.com/blog/prevent-laravel-xss-exploits/

Comment: as you mentioned the eval is running in client side. so its client responsibility to cleanup the data getting from API. as the API is not only desinged for browser it can be rendered in mobile , desktop any where, For API its just string of data.

Comment: Sure, the client side must need to do this check, but I usually double-check, the API and the clients too.